# oracle : why index full scan is used for group by clause on non-leading index column

Tags: oracle, indexing

i have a table EMPLOYEE, a normal composite index on (id,sex),

and the SQL is as follows:

```
select sex,count(*) from employee group by sex;

Plan hash value: 1246558535

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |            |     2 |     4 |     2  (50)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY   |            |     2 |     4 |     2  (50)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN| IDX_ID_SEX |   104 |   208 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------------
     11  recursive calls
      0  db block gets
     11  consistent gets
      0  physical reads
      0  redo size
    673  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
    552  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
      2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
      0  sorts (memory)
      0  sorts (disk)
      2  rows processed
```

index full scan is used, i am curious here:
why use index full scan but not index fast full scan ? my understanding: for index full scan, data is returned in sorted order, as column "sex" is not leading column in composite index, it can not be returned in its sorted order, why use index full scan here ?

Comment: Your query has no `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause, which basically means that Oracle has to read every record in the table to get the result set.  If it's using an index, it must have concluded that doing so would be faster than just a brute force table scan.  But, don't take this the wrong way and think that the index is helping your query.  It might help a little bit, but your query generally can't be improved using any index.

Comment: it has used the index, my question is: why index full scan but not index fast full scan ?

Comment: Can't it be because of [optimizer_index_cost_adj](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams144.htm#REFRN10143) because optimizer in some cases may [ignore it for ffs](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/oracle/index-costing-threat/)

Comment: after i change optimizer_index_cost_adj to 50, it still use index full scan,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update answer due to composite index**

I decided to update the answer based on the comments where you specify that index is composite.

- Index full scan reads each index node in SORTED order.
- Index fast full scan is used to retrieve table rows from the index in UNSORTED order.

**Index full scan**: Oracle will choose an index full scan when the CBO statistics indicate that a full-index scan is going to be more efficient than a full-table scan and a sort or group is done over the result set. The full-index scan is normally invoked when the CBO determines that a query will return numerous rows in index order, and a full-table scan, and a sort or group by option may cause a disk sort or hash operation go to the temporary tablespace.

**Fast full-index scan** This execution plan is invoked when a index contains all of the values required to satisfy the query and table access is not required. The fast full-index scan execution plan will read the entire index with multi-block reads (using db_file_multiblock_read_count) and return the rows in unsorted order.

In your specific case, it should have used a FAST FULL SCAN, but perhaps is either a problem in statistics or a optimizer_index_cost_adj parameter value too low.

Let me show you a test case. I create a table with an id field generated as identity, one field with the sex, either M or F, and a random string for the column c1.

```
SQL> create table test_index ( c1 varchar2(10), c2 number generated always as identity, c3 varchar2(1) );

Table created.
```

Populate 200000 records and create the index composite on c2 and c3

```
SQL> declare
  2  begin
  3  for r in 1 .. 100000
  4  loop
  5      insert into test_index ( c1 , c3 ) values ( dbms_random.string('U',1
  6      insert into test_index ( c1 , c3 ) values ( dbms_random.string('U',1
  7  end loop;
  8  commit;
  9  end;
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> create index idx_test_index on test_index (c2 , c3) ;

Index created.
```

Now, let's see how it behaves

```
SQL> select count(*) from cpl_rep.test_index ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
    200000

SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats ( 'MYOWNER', 'TEST_INDEX' , cascade => true );

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


SQL> set autotrace traceonly explain

SQL> set lines 200
SQL> select c3, count(*) from test_index group by c3

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 805205005

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |                |     2 |     4 |   102   (8)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY        |                |     2 |     4 |   102   (8)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| IDX_TEST_INDEX |   200K|   390K|    95   (2)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SQL> select /*+index ( a IDX_TEST_INDEX ) */ c3, count(*) from myowner.test_index a group by c3
  2  ;

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2605845939

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |                |     2 |     4 |   257   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY   |                |     2 |     4 |   257   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN| IDX_TEST_INDEX |   200K|   390K|   250   (1)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In my example it uses FAST FULL SCAN because of the value of optimizer_index_cost_adj

```
SQL> set autotrace off
SQL> show parameter index_cost_adj

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
optimizer_index_cost_adj             integer     100
```

Let's change it to a low value to see what happens

```
SQL> alter session set optimizer_index_cost_adj=20 ;

Session altered.

SQL> set autotrace traceonly explain
SQL> select c3, count(*) from cpl_rep.test_index group by c3 ;

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2605845939

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |                |     2 |     4 |    57  (13)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY   |                |     2 |     4 |    57  (13)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN| IDX_TEST_INDEX |   200K|   390K|    50   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The optimizer_index_cost_adj parameter was created to allow a change in the relative costs of full-scan versus index operations. This is the most important parameter of all, and the default setting of 100 is incorrect for most Oracle systems. It lets you tune optimizer behavior for access path selection to be more or less index friendly—that is, to make the optimizer more or less prone to selecting an index access path over a full table scan or a full index scan.

The default for this parameter is 100 percent, at which the optimizer evaluates index access paths at the regular cost. Any other value makes the optimizer evaluate the access path at that percentage of the regular cost. For example, a setting of 50 makes the index access path look half as expensive as normal.

Comment: thanks for your explaination, as the index is(id,sex), then the result from index reading will be sorted by id, not by sex, why optimizer just use index fast full scan to get the result quickly and then do the sorting,

Comment: so the index is composite, ok let me build a test case and I will post it

Comment: @tonyibm, I post a test case with some details. Hope it clarifies more the issue

Comment: thanks for your test case, i didn't change optimizer_index_cost_adj, it has default value of 100, but optimizer still use index full scan, why ?

Comment: you can change the value at session level and if you collect statistics you will see how it goes to index fast full scan. It is going for index full scan because optimizer index cost adj is 100, in that case the evaluation looks the same in a index full scan than in an index fast full scan, and Oracle will always use the latter. If you consider it will go faster with fast full scan, then switch session level for this statement or use the hint to change optimizer index cost adj

Comment: @tonyibm, I would really appreciate if you accept the answer, or at least upvote it .

Comment: Speaking about hints, if it's needed just for the specific query - you can try "index_ffs" hint to force index fast full scan

Comment: yes, use hints will do that, and i tried on some other table with much more data, it will use  index fast full scan as expected, don't understand how it is affected by data volume,